# Email instead of username in password grant

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I try to use email instead of username in ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant
I want the request to be like this

```
curl -u client_id:client_secret -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token -F grant_type=password -F email=example@example.com -F password=password -F scope=read
```

but i get an error{"error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing \"username\" in request."}

Answer (score 0):

ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant only supports `username` and `password` as the requesting parameters. If you wish to support `email`, you'd better customize `ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant` as:

```
def authenticate_user(self, username, password):
    if '@' in username:
        user = get_user_by_email(username)
    else:
        user = get_user_by_username(username)
    if user.check_password(password):
        return user
```

And you should still request with parameter `username`.